# netcat as a multithread server

Tags: netcat, parallel-processing

I use netcat to run a simple server like this:

`while true; do nc -l -p 2468 -e ./my_exe; done`

This way, anyone is able to connect to my host on port 2468 and talk with "my_exe".
Unfortunately, if someone else wants to connect during an open session, it would get a "Connection refused" error, because netcat is no longer in listening until the next "while" loop.

Is there a way to make netcat behave like a multi-threaded server, i.e. always in listening for incoming connections? If not, are there some workarounds for this?

Comment: You can use socat

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you are using the wrong tool for the task: use something like [ucspi-tcp](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html), especially [tcpserver](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html):

```
tcpserver waits for incoming connections and, for each connection, 
runs a program of your choice.
```

Comment: Where has this been all my life?!

Comment: Thanks @akira, can you provide the example?

Comment: e.g. `tcpserver localhost 2468 ./my_exe`

Answer (score 4):

Although you didn't mention the operating system you're using, I'll assume it's Linux or Unix based on the syntax of your shell command example.

If your system is running [xinetd](http://www.xinetd.org) (or its predecessor [inetd](http://linuxmanpages.com/man8/inetd.8.php)), you can use that software to listen for a connection on the port of your choice, and run an executable to respond.  With xinetd/inetd, you have the option of allowing multiple concurrent connections, each served by a separate instance of your executable.

Answer (score -3):

you could likely just background the process (then it doesn't wait for a return before stepping to the next loop) with an '&' such as:

```
while true; do nc -l -p 2468 -e ./my_exe &; done
```

Comment: That's going to spawn loads of subprocesses and crash the system....

Comment: And, only the first invocation will work; every succeeding one will fail because there's already a server socket on port 2468.